# Use RBF kernel with logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, kernel-trick

There are some resources online (e.g. [this one](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html)) on logistic regression with polynomial kernels, such as

$$h_\theta(x)=logistic(\theta_0 + \theta_1x1+ \theta_3x_1^2 + \theta_4x_2^2)$$

I'm wondering if it's possible to use RBF kernel $K_r(x,x')=\exp(-\frac{\|x-x'\|^2}{r})$ here. If so, what would $h_\theta(x)$ looks like?

Comment: It's not kernel. You just add nonlinear transformations of input variables to your existing input variables.

Answer (score 1):

For others who have similar questions, I found this paper by [Zhu and Hastie](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/jcgs02_c.pdf) ([doi:10.1198/106186005X25619](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/106186005X25619), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27594104?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), [Citeseer](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.516.2427&rep=rep1&type=pdf)$^\dagger$) very helpful.

By the representer theorem, $f_\theta(x)$ has the form:

$$f_\theta(x)=b + \sum_i ^ N a_i K(x, x_i) $$

So the probability is $p(x)=\frac{e^{f(x)}}{1+e^{f(x)}}$.

---

$^\dagger$ The link doesn't work.

Comment: @user777 Thanks. I think I'm asking for RBF kernel.

Comment: @user777 Of course it's not. It's nothing. It's just a quote from the resource I linked.

Comment: For efficient tuning of the hyper-parameters, see my paper (with Mrs Marsupial) "Efficient approximate leave-one-out cross-validation for kernel logistic regression" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10994-008-5055-9 (pre-print available here: http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/publications/pdf/ml2008a.pdf ).  We do use the RBF kernel in that paper.  KLR is a very useful machine learning algorithm.